# CORS & HTTP Options

Tags: chromecast, smooth-streaming

I have built a custom receiver app using Google's example for the chromecast.
I am trying to stream SmoothStreaming on it.
Problem is, that I see the networking debugger and I see that for every chunk of SS it fetches, it does HTTP OPTIONS before the HTTP GET.

Is there a way to use a CORS xml or something so that the chromecast will not do these overhead calls?

Thanks

Comment: HTTP OPTIONS is part of the CORS spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a CORS Proxy. Have you tried to use corsproxy.com? Or TOMODOKorz? Links:

- http://www.corsproxy.com/
- https://github.com/TOMODOcom/TOMODOkorz

From the tests I've been doing, the Chromecast client always sends HTTP OPTIONS to check it has permissions to get the content and then (after receiving a 200 OK) sends a POST to the license server.